# What's the go equivalent of reading from php standard input?

Tags: php, go, stdin

I'm porting a PHP script used to listen linux `supervisor`'s events.

It's probably a stupid question, but I cannot understand what is the equivalent of this

```
$fin = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
```

I need this because, when `supervisor` fires an event, also starts my script, and my script listen events reading from `php://stdin`

Comment: Not all people who write Go are necessarily familiar with PHP. Either you add the [php] tag to this question to get also PHP experts to chime in, or you have to clarify what exactly that code does in PHP. [Also have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73736940/golang-read-from-stdin-and-block-until-there-is-something-being-sent-to-stdin)

Comment: [os.Stdin](https://pkg.go.dev/os#pkg-variables) is automatically opened at program start. You can immediately start reading from it.

Comment: That was the glue I was missing: `os.Stdin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The read-only mode (`"r"`) on your fopen is [ignored by PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) for php:// handlers.

Depending on what you want to do, you can `io.ReadAll(os.Stdin)` or `bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)` (if you plan on line-by-line reading).